# How to group by in MongoDB Compass based on the time?

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Recently I'm working with a Mongodb database. Here is the data model of the document I need to run a query on:

```json
    {
      "creation_date": {
        "$date": {
          "$numberLong": "1641981205813"
        }
      },
      "user_id": {
        "$oid": "61dedd8b7a520461dd78016b"
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "61dede397a520461dd7818bd"
          },
          "product_id": {
            "$oid": "615071ae8b66e1e9a3d6ea50"
          },
          "payment": true,
          "support_all_payment": false,
          "term_ids": null
        }
      ],
      "carts_info": [
        {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "61dede397a520461dd7818be"
          },
          "support_type": null,
          "support_price": 0,
          "product_price": 11000,
          "product_type": "all",
          "final_price": 11000,
          "product_id": {
            "$oid": "615071ae8b66e1e9a3d6ea50"
          }
        }
      ],
      "_des": "initial_payment",
      "_type": "online",
      "_token": "9e0cb4d111f642f1a6f482bb04f1f57b",
      "_price": 11000,
      "_status": "unpaid",
      "_terminal_id": "12605682",
      "__v": 0,
      "additional_information": {
        "saman_bank": {
          "MID": "0",
          "ResNum": "61dede387a520461dd7818bb",
          "State": "CanceledByUser",
          "TraceNo": "",
          "Wage": "",
          "Rrn": "",
          "SecurePan": "",
          "HashedCardNumber": "",
          "Status": "1"
        }
      }
    }
```

This collection is user orders. I need to count the orders for today. So, I need such a equivalent query for Mongodb Compass the same as this SQL:

```sql
    SELECT count(1) num,
           date(creation_date) date
    FROM orders
    WHERE date(creation_date) = "2023-02-16"
    GROUP BY date
```

Any idea how can I run this logic on Mongodb Compass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$dateTrunc` to perform date only operations.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $dateTrunc: {
              date: "$creation_date",
              unit: "day"
            }
          },
          ISODate("2022-01-12")
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$creation_date",
          unit: "day"
        }
      },
      num: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l2vGXCRi7eP)

---

For OP's MongoDB v3.6, we can use `$dateToString` to perform string comparison on a date-only string.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      dateOnly: {
        "$dateToString": {
          "date": "$creation_date",
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      dateOnly: "2022-01-12"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      num: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AOV2uAAJSaj)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle you provided, but in the real database it throws "unrecognized error" https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF8Kx.png

Comment: MongoDB 3.6.8 Community

Comment: Thanks for you update, upvoted, but sadly this time it throws `MongoServerError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'`. Probably I'm using your query in the wrong way in MongoDB Compass.

Comment: Thanks ray, now it works, but doesn't return anything https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nEtq.png

Comment: You mean `db.orders.aggregate([` ?

Comment: @MartinAJ yes. You should do that.